# Disable App Nap in WKWebView Web Content process

Tags: .net, macos, webkit, wkwebview

I am developing a .NET MacOS app which uses the `WKWebView`. I am trying to implement the ability of miniaturizing the app without loss of the performance. The problem is that after around a minute the app slows down while being miniaturized. I have noticed that the "*Web Content*" process is napping at that time. I was able to block the nap of the app by using `NSProcessInfo` activity mechanism, but since web view spawns its own process it seems I cannot do the same with it because `NSProcessInfo` is only available to the current process.

Is there any way I could prevent the web view's process from napping then? Any help is appreciated.

[image: The first process is my app, the other one is the web view's one]